# My Visual Basic program has scaling problem on High-DPI display

Tags: vb.net, highdpi

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 with the latest updates. I had created a Windows Forms app with Visual Basic and .NET 6.0. My main display's resolution is 1920*1080 and the scale of Windows is %125.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGEbg.png)

In the beginning, everything was okay. The preview which I see on the designer was the same with the output/debug. VS was giving this error, but there was no problem with the resolution of my program:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpnUj.png)

I have worked on my project for a while and then, suddenly, it became blurry, like the old apps which doesn't support high-DPI displays (such as Bittorrent)

You can see the preview (on the left) and the real output (on the right).
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOE8g.png)

I tried the "Override high DPI scaling behavior" option as "Application" from the properties of the .exe file of the project:
[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDdpp.png)

It is better. However, it has some alignment problems, take a look at the text on the left-top corner. The second line of the text *TAKİP SİSTEMİ* is a bit on the right on the output.
[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12euY.png)

Also, all buttons are different: [Image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDuIM.png)

There weren't any alignment problems like that in the beginning.

I didn't change any of the settings. I just continued to develop my project, and suddenly it became blurry like I mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77737619/how-to-turn-off-different-dpi-scaling-in-winform/77753975#77753975 may be of help