# How to turn off different DPI scaling in winform?

Tags: winforms

I designed a few forms at 100% scaling at 1920x1080 resolution. When I change the resolution (to any) but leave the scaling at 100%, forms are scaled properly and all looks "perfect". When I change the scaling to 125/150%, forms become unusable (buttons overlapping etc. - total mess).

All my forms have `.AutoScaleMode` property set to `None` and `.AutoSize` property to `False`, target platform is .NET 4.5, forms are shown within MS Office application (forms are parts of an add-in). Forms contain multiple buttons, text boxes, panels, some are docked within the main form.

I have read multiple articles and almost all state that `.AutoScaleMode` should control the scaling (or not) of the winform, but it appears that it's not the case. I have played with different properties and nothing helped. I have read that .NET 4.8 might solve the problem and I can use some "DPI" functions on Load event but I do not know how to use these.

I launch forms using the following code:

```
        Dim frm As Form
        Try
            frm = New FrmCreator
            frm.ShowDialog()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log.Error(ex, "Error while showing creator form.")
        End Try
```

I have tried to change the settings in manifest file, but it didn't help at all:
[Post from SO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3UYb.png)

How can I turn off the scaling on my winforms? I have read of potential ways to make forms DPI scalable but I am too low-skilled person to implement it without help so I am looking for a simple workaround aka - turn off scaling completely.

Comment: Make your app DpiAware . Upgrade to .NET Framework 4.8, read here: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms). Add the `app.manifest` you haven't (you should manifest your app anyway), to specify the supported System versions. Use `app.config`, as described in the document, to specify a `PerMonitoirV2` DpiAwareness mode. Change `AutoScaleMode` to `Dpi`. Use `Segoe UI` as Font everywhere (anyway, not `Microsoft Sans Serif`)

Comment: If you leave your app DpiUnaware, when you create a Form in another DpiAware Process (as MS Office WPF applications), your application becomes automatically `SystemAware`. If you haven't designed your application to support DpiAwareness scaling, well, you have seen the result. You *could* force your application to be DpiUnaware and not to become DpiAware when part of DpiAware Process, but try not to -- If the `PerMonitorV2` mode make it difficult, change it to `SystemAware`, see whether you need less changes to the current layout

Comment: In case you need to call a Win32 function to set the DpiAwareness mode (sometimes needed when what's in the `app.manifest` / `app.config` is or can be ignored in some contexts), see the notes here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try to apply your recommendations to see the result. Do you think that my forms will scale properly after the changes? Can I even manually design my forms to look ok at different % scaling (for example, design form for 100%, 125%, 150% scaling separately in Visual Studio)?

Comment: Dpi scaling in WinForms is a *work in progress*. It got better in .NET 7+. In .NET Framework 4.8.x it's *decent*. You may need to partially redesign parts of your Forms (I don't know what kind of layout you have now), make use of auto-scaling containers, as the TableLayoutPanel, FlowLayoutPanel etc. and use nested containers - docked / anchored with care - to generate a layout that is less affected by mixed Dpi and Font scaling. Note that Dpi scaling is not the same thing as Font scaling, and you may have machines that scale both. Test a lot

Comment: Ok, thank you. Are there differences between different windows versions/build? For example, I develop on Win10, can different W10 build, or different windows version change look of my forms?

Comment: From Windows 10 Creators Update (1703), it's ~the same. It somewhat changes in Windows 11. You need a more solid design there -- WPF applications are `SystemAware` by default (as WinForms apps that target .NET 6+). But this depends on the choices the developers have made in this department. Keep it mind, make tests with both configurations. In general, if your application scales correctly when it's not part of another Process, it should behave as expected even when it is. But this can be verified only, as mentioned already, with a lot of tests (gets better when you get the hang of it)

Comment: It appears that changing app.config and app.manifest have no effect at all. I have tried multiple settings and the results are the same - form is messed up. Can I somehow turnoff scaling so that the form is the same (even if slightly blurred) across diferent scalings? If not - is there any way to manually design form for different scalings, even if it means creating a few versions of each form, each launched at different scaling? Looking for a solution good for newbie guy like me

Comment: Read again my third comment. Note that any Win32 function that sets the DpiAwaress mode, must be called before any UI element is created. Which includes your Form(s). Start with `PerMonitorV2`, then `SystemAware` if the former doesn't generate the expected behavior -- If you have tried something, post what you have done and a description of the result

Comment: As an add-in, you must follow the configuration imposed by the host application.  Any recent version of Office will declare themselves to be dpiAware, you must therefore ensure your form design/code can correctly handle that.  Which is usually not difficult, but we can't help you get there if you don't show us anything.

Answer (score 0):

"Answer" as a follow-up to Jimi explanations in comments to my original question.
My goal is to have my forms load with the same layout from 100% scaling on all scalings, which is why I want to make the form DPI unaware. I realize it will be processed as bitmap scaled up/down and will cause fonts and details to be blurry, but this is a workaround I will gladly accept.

I tried to implement functions from the following thread:
[DPI awareness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239138/dpi-awareness-unaware-in-one-release-system-aware-in-the-other/50276714#50276714)

Using the code below:

```
Private Declare Function GetWindowDpiAwarenessContext Lib "user32.dll" (hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function GetAwarenessFromDpiAwarenessContext Lib "user32.dll" (DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Declare Function SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext Lib "user32.dll" (value As Integer) As Integer

Public Sub New()
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application = AddinModule.CurrentInstance.ExcelApp
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = Nothing

    wb = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook
    Dim filename As String = wb.Name

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim processes() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel")
    For Each p As Process In processes
        If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(filename.Substring((filename.LastIndexOf("/") + 1))) Then
            k = GetAwarenessFromDpiAwarenessContext(GetWindowDpiAwarenessContext(p.MainWindowHandle))
        End If
    Next
    SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(k - 1)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End sub
```

I have placed above code in `New` block of my form, before initialization. I have extracted Excel process to get `.MainWindowHandle` and then process it further.
I am not sure if this is the correct way according to Jimi's comment "that it needs to be placed before any UI is created". Form is launched after clicking a Ribbon button in Excel.

Integer `k` returns `2` and then I subtract `1` to get correct `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT`.

The code above implies nothing in `app.config` related to DPI awareness and no `app.manifest` file within the solution + `.AutoScaleMode` of that form as `None`.

Unfortunately, it did not work. Form is not correctly shown. Is my implementation of the required functions wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in C# to solve Dpi distortions use in program main:

```
    Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.DpiUnaware);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```